# error persistence

Tags: jpa

que significa este error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/persistence/exceptions/PersistenceUnitLoadingException
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)

Comment: Hola Juan, podés mirar [acá](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233656/strange-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-in-eclipse) a ver si alguna respuesta te ayuda.